# Unexpected std::bad_cast thrown by binary_oarchive from the boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>

int main()
{
std::ofstream file("data.dat", std::ios_base::binary);
boost::archive::binary_oarchive oar(file);
return 0;
}
```

I compiled the above code with the following Makefile.

```
CC = g++

CFLAGS = -pedantic -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include

LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/lib -lboost_iostreams-mt -lboost_serialization-mt

all: test

test: test.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) test.o $(LDFLAGS) -o test

%.o: %.cpp
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
rm -f *.o
```

When I run the program, it throws an instance of `std::bad_cast`. The Problem lies in the call of `boost::archive::binary_oarchive oar(file);`. I presume, `file` is somehow not compatible with `binary_oarchive`. I'm working on a system with Mac OS X 10.6 and used homebrew some hours ago to install boost. This sample code was extracted from the answer of Emile Cormier from:

[Reading and writing C++ vector to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469531/reading-and-writing-c-vector-to-a-file)

There, I found a solution for writing vector-data to a file.

Edit: Does anybody know, why this program throws an 'std::bad_cast'? Is it possible, that this code runs on other machines and the problem is related to my system?

**Solution:**
To figure out, if my problem is related to some weird configuration error, I set up Linux Mint on another computer and tried to compile and run the above code there. Surprisingly, it didn't throw a "std::bad_cast". Then I uninstalled boost with homebrew and tried to compile the libraries with the instructions on the boost-Website and my preferred compiler gcc-4.9. After that, my code compiles and runs well.
I think the problem was, that the boost-libraries I used, were compiled with another compilerversion than I use on my own code.

Comment: Where does the file come from? What is your question?

Comment: binary archives are not portable, are you writing `data.dat` from the same system?