# how to write a vector to a file in binary mode using c++?

Tags: c++, vector

so far i tried this,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   unsigned short array[3]={0x20ac,0x20ac,0x20ac};
   vector<unsigned short> v;
   std::ofstream file;
   file.open("1.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
   file.write((char*)(array), sizeof(array));
   v.push_back(array[0]);
   v.push_back(array[1]);
   v.push_back(array[2]);
   file.write((char *)v,sizeof(v));
   file.close();
}
```

i get a error message 
stan.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
stan.cpp:21:23: error: invalid cast from type ‘std::vector’ to type ‘char*’.

Comment: You might take a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469531/reading-and-writing-c-vector-to-a-file?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either write each element one-by-one, or write the whole data by `write(v.data(), v.size() * sizeof(unsigned short))`

Comment: Usual comments about byte-order dependence apply. (ie. If you write data from a little endian machine, you'll have to do extra work on a big endian machine when reading it, and vice versa.)

Comment: Yes, byte-order should be considered depending on the actual usage of the code.

Comment: I like `sizeof(v[0])` better than `sizeof(unsigned short)` because if someone foolishly changes the type of the vector, the first form will not require updating, thus following the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the pointer to the first element, then calculate the number of bytes by the number of elements in v * sizeof an element:

```
file.write((char*)(&v[0]), v.size() * sizeof(v[0])) ;
```

output:

```
% od -x 1.txt
0000000 20ac 20ac 20ac
```